# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException while wiring up InternalResourceViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I'm currently trying to get integration tests running in our Spring MVC project. 
One of our components depends on the ViewResolver which gets autowired by Spring. It's configured in the test-context.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

However, this gives me an NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:

```
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#1
```

When I remove the InternalResourceViewResolver property from the test-context.xml, I get a

```
Caused by:               
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

How can that happen?